# HowTo use oldest DLL on VS2010 c# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll

I need to reference a oldest DLL (not .Net DLL) on a newest VS2010 c# project.
The DLL documentaztion show me how to use a ReadObject function:

MyDll rc=ReadObject (HEQUIP   hEquip,
            UCHAR  uchSegment,
            UCHAR  uchType,
            USHORT  usFirst,
            USHORT  usQty,
            PUCHAR pValue);

Also show how to use on VB6 project:

Declare Function ReadObject Lib "MyDll.dll" (ByVal DriverId As Integer, ByVal uchSegment As Byte, ByVal uchType As Byte, ByVal usFirst As Integer, ByVal usQty As Integer, ByRef pValue As Any) As Integer

Anyone can expla me how i can reference the DLL on c# project? Also the keywords "ByVal" and "ByRef" what are the correct conversions on c# language?
Thanks a lot for any suggestion

Jumpier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that by "oldest DLL" you mean a native DLL. To do that, you need to use [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx).

Make sure the DLL is in a location where the system can find it. Then, import the function like:

```
[DllImport("MyDll.dll"])
private static int ReadObject(...);
```

You need to pass the parameters using the conventions outlined in the above linked tutorial. My first shot would be:

```
[DllImport("MyDll.dll"])
private static int ReadObject(int driverId, byte segment, byte type, int first, int qty, ref byte value);
```

`ByVal` and `ByRef` are not valid in C#. You need to omit `ByVal` and change `ByRef` to `ref`.

Comment: I've try how you suggest. I've copied my .exe and MyDll.dll files inside the same folder then i run my application. When try to use ReadObject function i have this error: "Unable to load DLL 'MyDll.dll': I cant find the specified module. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"} System.DllNotFoundException. Some idea??

Comment: Fixed the attribute in my answer. Maybe your DLL depends on other DLLs?

Comment: No, the DLL is standalone. What you means with "Fixed the attribute in my answer"?? Thanks

Comment: I forgot to include the name of the DLL to be loaded in the `DllImport` attribute. I changed that in my answer.

Comment: update ...

i've read in .DLL documentation that some time call the library as "MyDll.dll" and some other "My Dll.dll" (space between "My" and "Dll.dll"). I've try to rename dll from "MyDll.dll" to "My Dll.dll" and now using [DllImport("My Dll.dll"]) working fine. I don't know why .... (may be .DLL internal reference). Thanks Thorsten Dittmar